# Hearthstone: Destroy and Deathrattle effect

Tags: hearthstone

There are some cards that has the word "destroy a friendly minion".

I was wondering does that stop deathrattle effects from firing off?

IE for example if I have a ravenous pterrordax (destroy minion to adapt twice) in my hand and I cast it on a dreadsteed (at turn end will summon another dreadsteed deathrattle). Will it prevent that deathrattle from firing off?

I am thinking of maybe trying to put dreadsteed's deathrattle to use in the new knight of the frozen throne expansion wild deck.

Comment: As a sidenote: "destroy" cards _do_ circumvent minions that trigger an effect when taking damage (e.g. acolyte of pain).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it does not prevent it from going off **UNLESS** they are silenced.If they are silenced, deathrattle has no effect.